# Cant Inject Stateless Beans from other Projects

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, cdi, java-ee-7

i have the problem that when i try to inject the Bean from Maven Project A which is packaged in a jar, in my main project.

Main Project with the controller :

```
package com.swapIt.register.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import com.svSwapIt.JPA.com.baustein.reg.ControllerHalloWorld;
import com.swapIt.register.Model.Person;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ControllerRegistration implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Person person;
    @Inject
    private ControllerHalloWorld rm;;

    public Person getPerson(){
        if(this.person == null){
            this.person = new Person();
        }
        return this.person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person){
        this.person = person;
    }

        public String nav2Danke(){

        return "/contentFrame/registerDanke.xhtml";
    }

    public String getGreeting(){
        return rm.getGreeiting();
    }
}
```

Project A (in jar):

```
package com.svSwapIt.JPA.com.baustein.reg;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class ControllerHalloWorld {

    public String getGreeiting() {
        return "Hallo World";
    }

}
```

I get the error message:

Target Unreachable, identifier 'controllerRegistration' resolved to null.

I know its because of the @Inject Annotation. Can please someone help me. I tried nearly everything. Is there something special i have to consider then Inject beans from another project except of to add the dependency in the main project?

My Beans XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you add a `bean.xml` to Project A?  Could you post it?  Which app server?

Comment: Tanks for answer. I use a wildlfy 8.2.1. Beans.xml is included in META-INF in Both Projects.

Comment: Post my beans.xml above. Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the "Target Unreachable, identifier 'controllerRegistration' resolved to null." error. This is the `@Named` bean and not the name of the hello world EJB.  Where does this error occur?  On the view?  Or at deployment time?

Comment: It occurs on the view, when i open the registration form...But when i remove the @inject annotation in ControllerRegistration it works and no error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In your class ControllerHalloWorld you can add the anotation @LocalBean
And in your instead @inject you can use @EJB Anotation. Is just a sugestion, i'm not sure if it's gone work, but try its free.
Hope it works.

Comment: I tried it with ManagedBean and EJB Annotation in main project for injection and with LocalBean in the jar project. Now i get the error during deploying: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.swapIt.register.controller.ControllerRegistration with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.swapIt-app.war:main" from Service Module Loader